# Best data structure to implement the APIs for Game Scoreboard

Tags: java, data-structures

I want to design a Scoreboard for a game. The score board is sorted in descending order, based on score. The Scoreboard looks like below:
-----------------------------
|User Name     | score       |
-----------------------------
|DragonSlayer | 98765       |
|Pikachu               | 98762       |
......
|User123              | 12568       |
-----------------------------

The basic APIs that needs to be supported are: 
`String getLeader()` -> returns the user name which is currently at the top of the leaderboard.
`int getScore(username)` -> returns the corresponding score for a given username.
`List<UserAndScore> getTop(int n)` -> returns top n number of usernames and their corresponding score.
`void insert(String userName, int score)` -> insert the score for a given user.

What could be the best data structure (in terms of speed) for working with the leaderboard.
I have thought of using 2 data structures and their corresponding time complexity for each API:

1. `HashMap` -> `getLeader()` API takes O(n). `getScore()` API takes O(1), `getTop()` API takes O(nlogn) (where O(nlogn) is the time taken for sorting the values in map and insert API takes O(1).
2. `LinkedList` -> While inserting the data, I would ensure that the data are in descending order. `getLeader()` API takes O(1), as we are returning the first element, `getScore()` API takes O(n), `getTop()` API takes O(1) and insert API takes O(n).

I'm more leaning towards using `LinkedList` as it is a leaderboard and `getLeader()` and `getTop(n)` are the frequently called APIs.

I thought of using a `TreeMap`. If I use the 'username' as key, the data would be ordered by username, but, I would like to have it by score though. It is not right to use the 'score' as the key in the `TreeMap`.

is there a data structure which could be having time complexity less than the `LinkedList` implementation?

is there a better data structure for implementing this scenario?

Thanks,
Pal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have both in maps, just create an enclosing class to make the invariants satisfied. For example

```
static class Bimap {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    SortedMap<Integer, Set<String>> rmap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

    // top score can have more than one entry
    // or user getTop(1).
    List<String> getLeader() {
        return new ArrayList<>(rmap.get(rmap.firstKey()));
    }

    int getScore(String username) {
        return map.get(username);
    }

    List<String> getTop(int n) {
        List<String> top = new ArrayList<>();
        int counter=0;
        for(Integer score : rmap.keySet()) {
            top.addAll(rmap.get(score));
            counter++;
            if(counter >= n) break;
        }
        return top;
    }

    // not to leave obsolete scores to keep the invariants satisfied
    void insert(String userName, int score) {
        Integer pscore = map.put(userName, score);
        if (null != pscore) {
            Set<String> names = rmap.get(pscore);
            names.remove(userName);
            if (names.size() == 0) {
                rmap.remove(pscore);
            }
        }
        rmap.computeIfAbsent(score, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(userName);
    }

}
```

Not tested except few trivial cases.  Caveat Emptor!